# android scrollview beside textview and buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I am trying to add a `scrollview` to the left of some fixed components.  I cannot get this to work.  I am trying to have 10 `buttons` on the left that scroll up and down.  Then, on the right are some additional elements and below the scrollbar/fixed text I have 3 additional `buttons`.

No matter what combination of `ScrollBar` and `LinearLayouts` I use, I have not been able to get this to work. I created the layout below as the baseline.

Thanks in advance.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Screen Title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="26dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget98"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llStdOptions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".8"
                android:fadingEdgeLength="30dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llStdOptionsPt2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight=".1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="10dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn1"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B1"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn2"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B2"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn3"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B3"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn4"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B4"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn5"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B5"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn6"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B6"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn7"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B7"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn8"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B7"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn9"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B7"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn10"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B7"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llAdvanced"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etText"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:editable="false"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="Test Text Line 1 " />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Select one"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/widget98"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnBBlack"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="sel1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnBWhite"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="sel2" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnBColor"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="sel3" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Select two"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/widget98"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnTBlack"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="sel1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnTWhite"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="sel2" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnTColor"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="sel3" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget98"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="93dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReset"
            android:layout_width="93dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Reset" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="93dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Save" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/linespacer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I might suggest looking into using relativeLayout, and then position items relative to each other..  or if you are bent on using linearLayout try messing with the layout_weights, they seem to be not adding up to 100%

Comment: You problem might be `android:layout_weight=".1"` for *llStdOptions*. Try to set it to 1.0 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let try this hope this one will helps you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Screen Title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="26dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget98"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llStdOptions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".8"
                android:fadingEdgeLength="30dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llStdOptionsPt2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight=".1"
                    android:
                    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="10dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn1"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B1"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn2"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B2"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn3"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B3"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn4"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B4"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn5"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B5"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn6"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B6"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn7"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B7"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn8"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B7"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn9"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B7"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn10"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B7"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llAdvanced"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etText"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:editable="false"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="Test Text Line 1 " />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Select one"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/widget98"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnBBlack"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="sel1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnBWhite"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="sel2" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnBColor"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="sel3" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Select two"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/widget98"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnTBlack"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="sel1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnTWhite"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="sel2" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnTColor"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="sel3" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget98"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="93dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReset"
            android:layout_width="93dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Reset" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="93dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Save" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/linespacer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I spoke too soon.  This works with 7 buttons, but with more, the top button starts scrolled off the top and you cannot access it.

Comment: then why you are using scrolview on there

Comment: Because I need all 10 buttons to be available for selections.

Comment: OK in scroll you can see the seven buttons then you need to scroll down for see a next three buttons.

Comment: I'm trying to fix all 10 buttons as visible but i can't. try this give a scroll view for whole layouts next to **screen title** Hope all buttons are visible.

Comment: I was wrong.  This did work.  I had a margin in set the production code that caused the top button to be located above the scrollable region.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Screen Title"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="26dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget98"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llStdOptions"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="30dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llStdOptionsPt2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn1"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="B1"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn2"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="B2"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn3"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="B3"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn4"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="B4"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn5"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="B5"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn6"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="B6"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn7"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="B7"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn8"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="B7"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn9"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="B7"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn10"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="B7"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llAdvanced"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".7"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etText"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:editable="false"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Test Text Line 1 " />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Select one"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/widget98"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnBBlack"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="sel1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnBWhite"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="sel2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnBColor"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="sel3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Select two"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/widget98"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnTBlack"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="sel1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnTWhite"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="sel2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnTColor"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="sel3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget98"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="93dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnReset"
        android:layout_width="93dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Reset" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="93dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Save" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/linespacer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know if it is what you want.

Comment: This does not work. Button1 is off the top of the screen and button2 only displays 1/4 of the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way hope this will help you...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Screen Title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="26dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llStdOptions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fadingEdgeLength="30dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llStdOptionsPt2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="10dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn1"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B1"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn2"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B2"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn3"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B3"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn4"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B4"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn5"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B5"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn6"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B6"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn7"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B7"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn8"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B7"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn9"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B7"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn10"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="B7"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llAdvanced"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:visibility="visible" >


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etText"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:editable="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="Test Text Line 1 " />



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Select one"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnBBlack"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="sel1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnBWhite"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="sel2" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnBColor"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="sel3" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Select two"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnTBlack"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="sel1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnTWhite"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="sel2" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnTColor"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="sel3" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget98"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReset"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Reset" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Save" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/linespacer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This does not work.  Button1 is off the top of the screen and button2 only displays 1/4 of the button.